# php: how i can replace the infinite while loop in client-server communication with someone else to achieve same server service

Tags: php, client-server, infinite-loop, server-push

I am building a client server real time communication application in php, where i want to implement true server push with optimization.

I know already the other techniques that came under Comet technique, for this i am using php socket server and socket applet client, every thing is going fine till now.

The problem is on server side infinite while that is used for listening incoming connections, it degrades my application's optimization.

How can I replace the infinite while loop in client-server communication with something else to achieve the server-push functionality? The moment a client pings the server, the connection is made to the client for communication.

Comment: " how i can replace the infinite while loop in client-server communication with someone else" Are you saying you want to replace the computer logic by a person?

Comment: no .. the question is how can i keep my socket server's socket open continuously without infinite loop to listen incoming client requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want asynchronous server on PHP try [PHPDaemon](https://github.com/kakserpom/phpdaemon)

Comment: its all about HTTP, but i am concerning with TCP protocol